# Lost Connection to MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query with Temp table for Codeigniter. It returns almost 25000 rows.
But when I use this query on live server, it loses DB connection.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT temp.id office_id, 
       temp.office_name, 
       temp.svcic,
       count(service_transaction.service_id) AS service_total 
  FROM (SELECT users.id, users.office_name, service_list.id svcic 
          FROM users,service_list 
         WHERE users.del_status = 0 
           AND users.type='agency' 
           AND service_list.del_status = 0 
           AND users.id != '-1' ) temp 
     LEFT JOIN service ON temp.id = service.office_id 
           AND service.del_status=0 
           AND (service.date 
       BETWEEN '2017-07-26' 
           AND '2017-08-26' ) 
     LEFT JOIN service_transaction ON service_transaction.service_id = temp.svcic 
           AND service_transaction.service_transaction_id=service.id 
     LEFT JOIN recipient ON recipient.id =service.recipient_number 
           AND recipient.gender != 'all' 
      GROUP BY temp.id, 
               temp.office_name, 
               temp.svcic 
      ORDER BY temp.office_name
```

How can I simplify query without using temp. I believe it happened for Temp table.

Comment: Have you looked at the application logs or the database logs? A query is not to blame for a connection lost. I think that the problem is about the time the query spent on running which causes the connection time to time out. Check your application timeout limit and also the database timeout limit.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding one of the reason could be

innodb_buffer_pool_size could be set to be larger than the RAM size available on the server.  The fix could be  to update my.cnf with the correct setting for innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Comment: I'm using shared hosting on reseller club. So, Can I increase innodb_buffer_pool_size on cpanel ?